# Parsing strings of different lengths

Tags: r

I have a vector that contains aggregated information about a product. An example would be `D | @ | W2222 | @G`. The only information I need out of this string is the "W2222" which denotes color. My problem is that I am not sure how to apply a consistent split because the "D" on the left can range from a single letter to a full string as well and the colors can be letter/number combinations or actual words. My code uses strsplit and unlist to separate out the colors, but also puts each character into its own row, so the color is still not able to be pulled out. How would I be able to get the color out regardless of its length or code?

Code:

```
Monster  <- MyData$ProductionScheduleDesc
Rockstar <- unlist((strsplit(as.character(Monster),"|"))) %>%
as.data.frame()
```

Output:

```
D

|

@

|

W
2
2
2
2



|

@
G
```

Comment: This is Pipe-Separated Value (PSV). Are you aware that `read.csv(..., sep = '|' )` does the split for you automatically? It doesn't matter what the field lengths are. Your question is simply *"Parse PSV into fields"*

Comment: `read.csv()` is not just for files, it can equally parse textConnections too. Retitled the other question *"Read PSV format"*. Either this should be closed as duplicate, or we should have a canonical *"Read PSV format file or string"*

Comment: | is a special character for defining split expressions. To split on a literal | you need fixed=TRUE `sapply(strsplit(x, "|", fixed=TRUE), function(x) trimws(x[3]))` or you could escape the special character: `sapply(strsplit(x, "\\s*\\|\\s*"), function(x) x[3])`. As smci mentioned, you might be able to fix this earlier, when reading the data in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to work through this by adding to the delimiter and expanding it to

```
Rockstar <- unlist((strsplit(as.character(Monster)," |@ "))) %>%
```

rather than just leaving it with the single |. This allowed all characters that are not separated with a space to remain grouped together, which in this case is only the color codes for my products.